# AWS Code Deploy: How to execute terminal commands on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami, aws-code-deploy

I am new to *AWS CodeDeploy*, I am following [this](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/) tutorial where it let you run commands like `mkdir`, `cp` and `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`.

THe reason I need to automate it that everytime a new build be deployed so direction creation and other thing need to be automated. I could not find the way how to do it while deploying a build on existing EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the code deploy, you can specify inside you appspec file some hooks that get run when deployed. You can run those hooks in different parts of the deployment.

Ex: BeforeInstall, ApplicationStop, etc

```
hooks:
    deployment-lifecycle-event-name:
        - location: script-location
        timeout: timeout-in-seconds
        runas: user-name
```

Reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-example.html